# How many non isomorphic trees with four vertices are there? What are they?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

As of now I have 4 assuming I got this right. I apologize for formatting because I have no idea how I'd display this in text but here I go.
a b c d are my points. - means there is a connection between them

I have

a - b, b - c, c - d

a - b, b - c,b - d

a - b, a - c, b - d

a -b, a - c, a - d

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually just two, and you’ve found each of them twice.

Your first and third trees are isomorphic: the third is c--a--b--d and is thus a single chain, like the first. Similarly, your second and fourth are isomorphic: each has a single vertex of degree $3$ connected to three vertices of degree $1$.

Once you have a vertex of degree $2$, like this:

```
*----*----*
```

there really are only two ways to proceed. You can attach the fourth vertex to the vertex of degree $2$ to get your second and fourth trees, or you can attach it to one of the vertices of degree $1$ to get your first and third trees.

Comment: great answer and I totally see it now that you pointed it out. Thanks man!

Comment: @imarben007: You're welcome!